# Cannot set https proxy in nw.js (former node-webkit)

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit, nw.js

http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/References/App/#appsetproxyconfigconfig-pac_url I learned here that it's possible to set https proxy in nw.js. But my simple script doesn't work. After initializing it I visit a page in my browser but my IP doesn't change. What am I doing wrong?

```html
<script>
var gui = require('nw.gui');
gui.App.setProxyConfig("https=uk.freevpn.pw:443");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's sad that nobody has answered this question.

The documentation at http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/References/App/#appsetproxyconfigconfig-pac_url has left me in the lost.

So after little bit research I managed get this working by utilizing the second argument of App.setProxyConfig.

**Step 1. Loading .pac file**

Create proxy.pac file in your root directory of your nw js application and put below configuration inside that file :

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{
    return "PROXY proxy.example.com:8080; DIRECT";
}
```

Here is some reference for .pac file :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Proxy_servers_and_tunneling/Proxy_Auto-Configuration_(PAC)_file

**step 2. Loading .pac file**

You just need to run this single line of code below to load the proxy configuration.

```
nw.App.setProxyConfig("", "file://"+__dirname+"\\proxy.pac")
```

Left the first argument blank (by using blank string).

After that, all of your network request will follow the set of rule you write on proxy.pac.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar, and it's insane how bad the docs are/how little help is available. My code below:
    
    `var pacFile = path.join(__dirname,'proxy-configs/nw-proxy.pac');

    fs.writeFileSync(pacFile,createPacProxy(host,portNum,scheme));

    ngui.App.setProxyConfig('','file://' + pacFile);`

should generate a PAC file and then use it to configure network requests. The file is correctly generated in the expected location, but when I run `ngui.App.getProxyForURL("http://example.com");` I can see that no proxy is being set.